# Why am I getting Invalid SNS topic ARN when creating a Budget Alert

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm simply attempting to setup a budget alert buy am getting the error *Invalid SNS topic ARN* when attempting to specify an SNS ARN for the alert.

I followed the steps below:

1. Created a new SNS Topic with SMS as the protocol.
2. Created a subscription to the topic (a US phone number).
3. Tested the subscription by sending a text (this worked).
4. Copied the *ARN* under the ARN column on the Topics section in AWS SNS.
5. Checked *Notify via Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) topic* and entered the ARN from #4.
6. I get the error *Invalid SNS topic ARN* next to the *SNS Topic ARN* field, immediately after copying-and-pasting the ARN into the field.

What's up? I know it's the correct ARN because I copied it directly from the console. Also, as far as I understand, Budgets and their alerts aren't tied the a specific region, although SNS Topics are (the topic is in us-east-2 N. Virginia).

Please let me know if you need more specifics.

Comment: Could you please verify whether the SNS topic has the policy as mentioned in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/budgets-sns-policy.html

Comment: In my case I had both SES and SNS topics within one region, but was trying to encrypt the SNS topic using KMS key created within other region.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you have allowed budget.amazonaws.com to be able to publish messages to this SNS topic in the SNS topic's resource based policy.

Add the following statement to the policy

```
{
    "Sid": "ExampleSid123456789012",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "budgets.amazonaws.com"
     },
    "Action": "SNS:Publish",
    "Resource": "your topic ARN"
}
```

Hope it works!

Comment: I try to follow the same above flow steps, but still not work. would you kindly advise on it?

Answer (score 6):

I only got it fixed when I created a **standard topic** (FIFO didn't work).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**I got the same problem before, but was able to solved by these steps,**

> "Please comply with SNS ARN format"

[image]

**My workaround was**

-

**1.** Create an **SNS Topic** in **US-EAST-1** region

**2.** Just used **Basic Access policy**

**3.** **(Optional)** publish and subscribe field,  I used the option : **Only the specified AWS account**, pasted my AWS account ID

[image]

**4.** **Edit SNS Topic and Enable access policy**,by adding the service  **budgets.amazonaws.com** , in ***SNS:Publish*** action
just follow and copy the format in the picture below, Then saved

[image]

**5.** **After successfully created the SNS topic** , I reloaded the configure
    alert page, then **pasted the SNS topic ARN**. No more Errors and can
    already **confirm budget**,

[image]

**You will receive a confirmation Email.**

With this content

> *Congratulations, you have successfully verified your SNS topic for AWS Budgets! You can now receive your AWS Budgets notifications
>   through this SNS topic.*

Answer (score 1):

Just as a minor point to this, after following the above steps, it still was not working. I discovered that if you have "Encryption" enabled on the SNS topic it will not work. Disabling this on the topic and refreshing the Budget edit screen fixed it!

Comment: Thanks.  This was the issue for me and removing encryption from topic solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is what I experienced.

- Started to create AWS billing alert
- Tried to use existing SNS topic, got the same error message you did.  Interestingly if you have a syntax error in your SNS ARN you will get different error message 'Please comply with SNS ARN format'.
- Thought that SNS topic should be in US-EAST region.  Created one there just for billing alerts.  Still same error message.
- Realized that topic must have correct policy attached to it. Added policy statement similar to what @mmal suggested.  Still same error message.

But then I just reloaded the page and tried to create billing alert from scratch.

And second time it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the policy just below  **"Statement": [** on the existing SNS Access policy.

```
{
  "Sid": "AWSBudgets-notification-1",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "Service": "budgets.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "Action": "SNS:Publish",
  "Resource": "SNS-policy-ARN"
},
```

Makesure not to miss the comma at the end.
SNS-policy-ARN is the ARN of the same SNS topic

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this in a .net application, with your AWS credentials in your ~/.AWS/credentials file, ensure that the Region that is defined in your appsettings.json matches the region in which your SNS Topic exists.

```
{
    "AWS": {
        "Profile": "myProfile",
        "Region": "eu-west-2"
    },
    ...
```